# Minimum distance between two finite right circular cylinders

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, computational-mathematics, computational-geometry

Given two right circular cylinders $C_0$ and $C_1$ represented by their axis endpoints $P_{00}$, $P_{01}$, $P_{10}$, $P_{11}$ and radii $r_0$, $r_1$. All the parameters are finite. How to calculate the minimum distance between them?

Comment: If these are *circular* right cylinders, the minimum distance between them is easily found from the minimum distance between their axes.

Comment: @hardmath Surely you need more than the minimum distance between axes. Given just a minimum distance between axes $d_A$, the cylinders could separated by any distance between $d_A$ (if the cylinders are end-to-end) and $d_A-r_0-r_1$ (if the cylinders are side-by-side).

Comment: Are you assuming the height of the cylinders is infinite? Because if so, that greatly simplifies this problem

Comment: As written in the question the cylinders $C_i$ are given in terms of their axis endpoints $P_{i0}$ and $P_{i1}$. These coordinates are finite.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie:  Yes, for two infinite cylinders the distance between axes is adjusted by subtracting the sum of radii (if that gives positive separation), even if the axes are skew.  The case of finite cylinders is more complicated, but that distance is bounded below by the distance between their infinite counterparts.